# Список из fragment заходи за BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin

Возникла проблема с корректным отображением фрагментов при использовании BottomNavigationView. Данные фрагментов заходят под BottomNavigationView. Тут скорее всего надо что-то делать в activity я думаю.

activity_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".actyvities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_event -> {
                val fragment =
                    EventFragment()
                addFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true

            }
            R.id.navigation_person -> {
                val fragment =
                    PersonFragment()
                addFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_reports -> {
                val fragment =
                    ReportFragment()
                addFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_settings -> {
                val fragment =
                    SettingsFragment()
                addFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)


        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
        val fragment = EventFragment()
        addFragment(fragment)




    }
   private fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.javaClass.getSimpleName())
            .commit()
    }
```

один из фрагментов:

```
class PersonFragment: Fragment() {
    val list = ArrayList<Person>()
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_persons,container,false)
        loadPersonList()
        showPersonList(myView)
        return myView
    }
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        }


    fun showPersonList(view: View){
        val  myListView = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.lvPerson)
        myListView.adapter = PersonAdapter(
            layoutInflater.context,
            listOfPerson = list
        )

    }

    fun loadPersonList(){
        list.add(Person("Иванов Иван"))
        list.add(Person("Петров Петр"))
        list.add(Person("Сергеев Сергей"))
        list.add(Person("Иванов Иван"))
        list.add(Person("Петров Петр"))
        list.add(Person("Сергеев Сергей"))
        list.add(Person("Иванов Иван"))
        list.add(Person("Петров Петр"))
        list.add(Person("Сергеев Сергей"))
        list.add(Person("Иванов Иван"))
        list.add(Person("Петров Петр"))
        list.add(Person("Сергеев Сергей"))
        list.add(Person("Иванов Иван"))
        list.add(Person("Петров Петр"))
        list.add(Person("Сергеев Сергей"))
    }
```

fragmen_persons.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="3dp">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/team"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="32"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvPerson"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_24dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Во фрагменте для тестирования я накидал список, при отображении люди из списка  и fab заходят по BottomNavigationView. Как исправить? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: а в чем именно проблема?

Comment: Элементы из списка находятся под панелью кнопок BottomNavigationView. А мне нужно чтобы данные на заходили под панель.

Comment: тут проблема в разметке контейнера

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае вы используете в качестве контейнера родительское вью в котором так же находится bottomNavigation:

```
android:id="@+id/container"
```

Навигация при помощи `BottomNavigationView` делается немного не так как у вас представлено. Для того чтобы можно было менять фрагменты используется контейнер. Вот пример разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentContainerT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation_t"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_nav_menu" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

В дальнейшем будет использоваться `FrameLayout`. Для того чтобы весь контент фрагмента был на экране а не под навигационной панелью, используется `margin_bottom`:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
```

То есть логика данного тега в том, что он приподнимает контейнер над вашим `Bottom_Navigation_View`. Пересмотрите разметку вашего контейнера, и если там нет `margin_bottom` то добавьте его. Но все-таки лучше добавить в родительский макет еще и контейнер, как вью, а не использовать родительский макет как контейнер. Потому что если вы добавите в родительское вью указанный марджин то у вас приподнимется все вместе с `bottomNavigationView`.